# SESSION not remembered php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I came across the problem that my session vars aren't remembered when you are linked to another page. This might sound a bit strange. To clear it up a bit, I will explain my problem with some code:

This code is a snippet from 'Login.php'. Here I set the SESSION vars for Email and wachtwoord(Password).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' AND Wachtwoord='$Wachtwoord'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or 
die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['wachtwoord'] = $Wachtwoord;


$sql = "UPDATE user SET Ingelogd = 1 WHERE Email='$email'";
$ressql = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or 
die(mysqli_error($connection));

}else{
    echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
```

Inside this snippet, the email and wachtwoord session are correctly set(I believe, because I can echo these and get the right output)

But when the user gets redirected to chat.php which contains this php code(indirectly, this code is in 'LoginCheck.php'. Linked to as: `Include('../Php/LoginCheck.php');`):

```
Include('connect.php');
//IF ((! $_SESSION['email']= NULL)&&(! $_SESSION['wachtwoord']=NULL)){
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    echo $_SESSION['email'];
    $Wachtwoord = $_SESSION['wachtwoord'];
    echo $_SESSION['wachtwoord'];
    echo 'something';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' and Wachtwoord='$Wachtwoord' and Ingelogd=1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if (!$count == 1){
 //header('Location: Login.php');   
}
//}
```

When php tries to do something with a SESSION var it gives this error: 
Undefined variable: _SESSION in F:\xampp\htdocs\Chives-Functional\Php\LoginCheck.php on line 4
The line, in which $email is declared.

What I want to check is whether the user is still logged in or not.
How can I get this to work? What am I doing wrong? And why isn't it remembered?
Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Kind Regards,

Ps. If more information is required, feel free to ask!

Comment: you need to call `session_start();` on every page

Comment: did you call `session_start()`?

Comment: add `session_start()` at the start of LoginCheck. It starts or resumes a session.

Comment: you are right, I'm sorry, I didn't know that

Comment: Your query is unsafe though. It is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should consider escaping your query variables using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: @RubenRutten I know it's unsafe but it doesn't need to be safe. It is just an informatics project. However, if I decide to do some serious projects in the future it's really handy to know. So thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Even if it is, you should never skip security, even if it's such an easy solution. I'm sure your teacher will appriciate it too.

Comment: @RubenRutten Yes, I think you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you made sure to start the session on top of every page?

```
session_start();
```